# How to measure the retention time of a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, cmos, cadence

I am trying to build a very simplisitic DRAM in cadence using MOM/MIM capacitors. I am using models from the CMOS and FD-SOI processes and I'd like to measure the retention time I can expect from either of these processes. I haven't built the DRAM yet. What sort of model I can use to get a good estimation of the retention time?

Answer (score 2):

Build it and simulate. The capacitor model should include leakage, but if it does not, you will have to find the technology description, oxide thicknesses and lookup the general leakage characteristics.

Generally in DRAM, switch leakage doesn't dominate, but with MOM/MIM capacitors it might be high, and extremely high at high temperatures and certain process corners. You can also simulate this in a straightforward manner.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I want to get an idea first of the retention times possible before building it. My question is, how to build a test circuit that can do that?